# How should I unit test a controller that returns a model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have a controller called `PostsController`

```
public class PostsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IPostsRepository repository;

    public PostsController(IPostsRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var posts =
            repository.All()
                      .OrderBy(post => post.PublishedAt);

        return View("Index", posts.MapTo<PostViewModel>());
    }
}
```

And a corresponding test fixture called `PostsControllerTest`

```
[TestFixture]
public class PostsControllerTest
{
    private PostsController controller;
    private Mock<IPostsRepository> repository;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        AutoMapperConfig.Configure();
        repository = new Mock<IPostsRepository>();
        controller = new PostsController(repository.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Index_ReturnsCorrectModel()
    {
        var actual = controller.Index().Model;

        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IEnumerable<PostViewModel>>(actual);
    }
}
```

At the moment I am only testing that the controller returns the correct model type. Should I also stub the repository and test that the correct data is returned like this:

```
[Test]
public void Index_ReturnsCorrectModel()
{
    var post = new Post
    {
        Slug = "continuing-to-an-outer-loop",
        Title = "Continuing to an outer loop",
        Summary = "When you have a nested loop, sometimes",
        Content = "When you have a nested loop, sometimes",
        PublishedAt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),
        Tags = new Collection<Tag> { new Tag { Name = "Programming" } }
    };
    repository.Setup(repo => repo.All()).Returns(new[] { post });

    var actual = controller.Index().Model as IEnumerable<PostViewModel>;
    Assert.NotNull(actual);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, actual.Count());
    Assert.AreEqual(post.Title, actual.First().Title);
}
```

I feel so frustrated not knowing if I am unit testing properly. A clear explanation of which I approach I should take why would be very helpful.

Comment: You have got the right sense of it. To unit test the controller, you want to make sure that the input - in this case the input is nothing - produces the correct output, and that all intended side-effects occur and no unintended side-effects occur. In this specific case, to test only the output as there are no side-effects to speak of, you only need to identify that what you setup in the repo is what you are getting. You can even rely on object to object comparison with `.AreSame()`, instead of testing equality of identifying properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to test the functionality of `IPostRepository` in this unit test. You should create a seperate unit test class for it.

Similarly the functionality of the `MapTo<T>` should be tested separately.

Unit tests should only test the functionality of the SUT (System Under Test) which in this case is the `Index` method of your `PostsController` class.

This is a simple method so the 2 things you want to be verifying in this unit test are:

1- The `repository.All()` method gets called once

2- Your view model is mapped correctly (which you are already doing)

This is how I would unit test this method:

```
[Test]
    public void Index_ReturnsCorrectModel()
    {
        // Arrange
        repository.Setup(repo => repo.All()).Returns(Enumerable.Empty<Post>());

        // Act
        var actual = controller.Index().Model;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IEnumerable<PostViewModel>>(actual);
        repository.Verify(repo => repo.All(), Times.Once);
    }
```

Also, to minimize the effort required to arrange your unit test, use can use a library like AutoFixture which will automatically create the post object for you.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Could you please explain why I need to supply the made-up post at all instead of only verifying that the `All` method was called once as you suggested in your first revision? Thanks. (please know that I do not expect you to answer these additional questions for the accept).

Comment: You don't. The only reason I put that in there is because your actual will return null and your Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IEnumerable<PostViewModel>>(actual) will fail. Not sure where your .MapTo<T> is coming from but you should probably mock that as well and verify that it has been called. Let me know which mapping library you're using (if any) and I'll update the answer.

Comment: I took your advice: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59537/concerns-about-the-correctness-of-my-repository-and-controller-tests#59537